# Are there tools to manage the power management for HDD?

Tags: power-management, hard-drive

I wonder if there are a better tool than the panel at *System → Preferences → Power Management*  to manage the power consumption for the HDD. Specifically HDD in a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment a bit with a few options for `hdparm` command. Specifically:

- `-S <number>` sets the idle timeout before the drive turns its spindle
  off.
- `-M <number>` sets the Acoustic Management Mode (this parameter also
  helps in the power management)

I don't report here how the value should be chosen, I let you to read it from the man page.

That said, I would NOT recommend to choose timeout values too short, as still one of the most stressing times for a hard disk is the spin-up time, i.e. it's better to leave a HDD spin a little longer while idling than continuously turn it off and on, especially with modern, low-power HDDs.